# Adicionando valores em tabelas existentes com RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r

Eu tinha feito antes uma pergunta sobre banco de dados Mysql em usando a library RODBC e devido a um erro nos tipos,eu vi em uma das respostas me falaram sobre a library RMySQL e resolvi experimentar ela.

Porém eu não estou conseguindo adicionar tabelas data.frame em uma tabela já existente.

Este é a tabela que fiz no mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE teste ( codigo varchar(5), nome varchar(5) );
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| codigo | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nome   | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

E este é o código que estou fazendo:

```
library(RMySQL)
#Criando conexão
con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),host = "localhost" ,dbname = "Banco",username= "****", password= "****")

#Listando tabelas
dbListTables(con)

#Elementos que serão adicionados
x = list("co1","nome1")
y = list("co2","nome2")

z = rbind(x,y)
colnames(z) = list("codigo","nome")
rownames(z) = NULL

z = data.frame(z)
#==============================

#Escrevendo elementos na tabela
dbWriteTable(con, name="teste", value=z ,overwrite = TRUE,row.names = FALSE)
```

Mas quando eu executo a ultima linha (escrever) o meu banco cria uma nova coluna e todos os tipos viram 'text':

```
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| row_names | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| codigo    | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nome      | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Como que eu poderia resolver isso e manter os tipos do mysql?

Comment: A resposta de Eduardo Leoni de certo?Se não monte a instrução sql diretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque overwrite=FALSE. Você está sobreescrevendo a tabela, por isso perde os tipos.